# need to capture lastmodifiedBy user and date of LWC in salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, schema, setup-audit-log

I have requirement where i need to fetch modified lwcComponent with the user who modified it programmatically.
Is there any soql query we can use or by apex schema we can get it.Audit trail does not capture LWC details.

Please suggest

Comment: You can query on "LightningComponentBundle" to get those details

Comment: getting error- sObject type 'LightningComponentBundle' is not supported.

Comment: in developer console

Comment: Please check "Use Tooling API"

Answer (score 0):

You can query on object LightningComponentBundle.

```
SELECT Id,masterlabel,lastmodifiedby.name,lastmodifieddate FROM LightningComponentBundle
```

Remember to check Tooling API checkbox when querying via developer console.

Note : We could query AuraDefinitionBundle without checking tooling api as well.